# How to efficiently calculate $(\sum {\bf M}^T{\bf DM}) {\bf v}$ for diagonal $\bf D$s and convolutional $\bf M$s?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, convolution, computational-mathematics

So I am currently working with some matrix-equation systems. 
I often come across expressions of the type $$\left( \sum_{\forall i} \alpha_i\cdot{{\bf M}_i}^T{\bf D}_i{\bf M}_i \right) {\bf v} $$

Where ${\bf M}_i$  are convolution matrices (Circulant or Toeplitz), ${\bf D}_i$ are diagonal matrices, $\alpha_i$ are scalars and ${\bf v}$ is a vector.

I want to be able to calculate this fast and preferably with as few reads and writes to memory as possible.

I am aware that if I had ${\bf D}_i = {\bf I}$ then ${{\bf M}_i^T {\bf M}_i}$ can be simplified to a new convolution matrix  with double size of convolution kernel, but these diagonal matrices seem to complicate things.

Comment: Is there any reason you prefer $\left(\sum \alpha_i M_i^\top D_i M_i\right) v$ over $\sum \alpha_i M_i^\top (D_i (M_i v))$? That is multiplying matrices instead of doing matrix-vector products (convolutions and scalings for your case)

Comment: @uranix several reasons to try and do it in one go. The time it takes to write and read to memory is one very good reason to try and clump together as many calculations before writing result to memory instead of doing read -> few calculations -> write -> read -> some more calculations -> write et.c.